# How to pass cookies as parameters from middleware from controller in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I am a beginner in laravel. I am trying to pass a parameter from middleware from controller like this:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['name']))
    {   
        return $next($request->attributes->add(['name' => strval($_COOKIE['name'])]));
    }
```

However, I got this error message:

> "Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::prepare() must be an
>   instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request, null given"

I tried to convert the cookie value as string before passing it, but it did not work. How can I pass the pass the cookie as parameter? I do not want to get the value of cookie using `$_COOKIE['name']`. My laravel version is 5.5. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try merging the cookie value in with the request input:

```
$merged = $request->merge(['name' => $request->cookie('name')]);

return $next($merged);
```

Keep in mind this will overwrite any input values named `name` so use a unique key.

However, this isn't really necessary, as the request has access to the cookie throughout it's lifecycle:

```
// MyController or MyModel or MyServiceProvider...
if (request()->hasCookie('name')) {
    $cookie = request()->cookie('name');
    // do stuff with cookie
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! However, how can I get the passed value in the controller?

Comment: In your controller function use `request()->cookie('name')->getValue();`. [Cookie Docs](https://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Cookie.html)

Comment: How about if I use merge() to pass parameters that is not cookie? There are two cases in my program (can read the cookie/cannot read the cookie). If the cookie can be read, the cookie will be passed to the controller. For another case, pass another value to the controller while the name of the parameter is the same as the first case.

Comment: If you use `merge` then it's accessible like any other input: `request()->input('name')`